# Two motherboards, same case, how best to proceed with GPU options? (Upgrade vs Replace)

Tags: graphics-cards, gaming, pc, sata, performance

I recently obtained an i7 8700k that is sitting at 5.0ghz without even trying under a D15s, all on an ASUS ROG Maximus Hero with 32GB of G.Skill TridentZ.  This was to replace my 4.78 Ghz i7 2600k that has half the RAM and is on an ASRock motherboard which appears to be having problems with its SATA ports.

When I made this change, I moved all of my SSDs over to the new machine.  I lucked out in that it was apparently similar enough not to flag my OEM Win10 too many points and trigger relicensing, so I now have a spare Win10 license I can use on the original motherboard.  The problem is, I also moved my only decent video card, a GTX 1070 FTW from EVGA (the 8GB variant).

Testing the drives, I found that the other HDDs in the machine may have killed the SATA ports they were on, but the motherboard might still be good.  In a hot-swap, the same drives detect as loaded with bad sectors and behave as if the interface boards were shot.   This puts me in a position full of choices, because my girlfriend would like to be able to game side-by-side instead of having to hunch over her laptop.

I have an HTC Vive, but otherwise game at 1080p with AA cranked.  The two motherboards are dual-mounted in a massive case on rollers, each plugged into different monitors.  The 1080 ti is brutally above MSRP wherever I look, because Bitcoin miners, but I'm not sure if a single 1070 ti is an upgrade worth the money, just to put the 1070 back in the 2600k, which still has some functional SATA ports left and a SATA expansion card in it. The same applies to the classical 1080, which is still quite expensive.  I've also contemplated just getting a second 1070 FTW from EVGA and going SLi in the new rig, but that would leave me still needing to buy a 1050 or 900-series or something AMD for the old one.

Option paralysis. I'm an avid gamer, a developer...pretty much if a PC is capable of it I do it. If I can 1080 ti close to MSRP I'd probably do it for greater compatibility with software and to keep an open PCI-E 8x slot.  If I can't, am I better to get another 1070 and rig up SLi, then get a third, lesser card?  Is the TI enough of an upgrade to the 1070 to justify a 1070 ti?  Is there an AMD equivalent which objectively outperforms the 1070 and would make sense for my VR setup?

Comment: Try looking at [benchmarks](http://gpuboss.com) as they will enable you find close if not exactly equivalent performing gpus.

Comment: Benchmarks I've used, but the problem with benching is that it often poorly reflects real-world application.  For instance, two 1070's will outperform a single 1080ti on paper, but in a game with poor SLi compatibility, the second GPU ends up unused and you take a net performance loss.   In other cases, the benchmark happens to be optimized for a certain driver set, and so newer equipment underperforms.  I've matched the benches, but considering the additional factors, I'm looking for more real-world data.

Comment: The link I gave you (GPUBoss) also contains actual data on the cpus (iex. performance/watt) if you're interested/can understand it. I'm not sure how you can get "more real-world data" without actually having the gpus on hand.

Comment: Unfortunately, GPUboss doesn't have the 1070ti, but UserBenchmarks did.  This doesn't account for SLi performance, though, so yeah, I'm looking for more anecodotal evidence to weight in as well.